# not a valid identifier - bash script error while execution

Tags: bash, unix

I'm getting following error while I try to capture process ids in my shell script.....

```
$bash ./restartjbossserver.sh
./restartjbossserver.sh: line 10: `i=$(ps -ef | grep "jboss" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')': not a valid identifier
```

And this is my script....

```
for i=$(ps -ef | grep "jboss" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')
do
echo $i
if [ $i != NULL ]
then
echo "Killing JBos Process.."
kill -9 $i
echo "Killed Joss Process..."
fi
done


sleep 10s

echo "Deleting JBoss Cache..."

rm -rf /home/cbsmsblapp/opt/EAP-6.3.0/jboss-eap-6.3/domain/tmp/*
echo " Deleted JBoss Cache..."


sleep 10s

nohup /home/cbsmsblapp/opt/EAP-6.3.0/jboss-eap-6.3/bin/domain.sh  & >nohup.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for iterating over a list is

```
for i in $( ...
```

not

```
for i=$( ...
```

Comment: It is working for `for i in` but after `do..done`, the rest of portion of the script is not executing. Do you have any suggestions for that....?

Comment: @DevAnandSadasivam: Run the script with `set -xv` to see what's going on.

Comment: ok I will do. I was little away from bash scripts. So I will be slow here. As per my observation `grep -v "grep"` to avoid killing grep process itself is not working. It looks like it kills on its own so `for` loop aborts operation after killing one among the process which was in `for` condition `grep -v "grep"` - `for i in $(ps -ef | grep "jboss" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')`.... Let me try the option which you had advised to me to do `set -xv`. And also let me combine grep in one statement and check. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't kill the grep, but the script itself?

Comment: Oh! I had that thought. But why & how it can be like that.....? sorry for asking.... Let me try so how it can be by.....

Comment: @DevAnandSadasivam: because `./restartjbossserver.sh` contains `jboss`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `pkill` and `pgrep` commands.  You could just `pkill jboss`.

Comment: Let me explore those commands `pkill` `pgrep`. Right now by seeing some other environment, I had corrected my `for` loop like `for i in $(ps -ef | grep "jboss" |  awk /-D[Controller]/'{print $2}')` and removed the second `grep -v "grep"` from the condition. But I wonder one of the line  doesn't have `-D[Controller]` but that is one among & part of  the JBoss domain process. I do not know the way how awk & sed works. I didn't execute the script so far as I cannot restart my JBoss instance now. Should be fine i hope. Thanks for your new introduction of commands, I will explore those. Thanks.

Comment: `grep -v "grep"` works fine problem was script name. Although if someone explain how `awk /-D[Controller]/'{print $2}` works when JBoss processes (one) doesn't have the term `Controller`..... is this because it has `-D` matches although.... and even the lines which has `Controller` it is not just next to `-D`..... I need to read about `sed` & `awk`.... Once again thanks for `pgrep` & `pkill`